# on Click running twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, alternation

http://jsfiddle.net/uTV5k/19/

Hello,

I am using the below script on my mobile site. Please see the jsfiddle of simulated script and markup.

The script below is exactly what's on my mobile site, and the js fiddle is a replicate of it.

In the jsfiddle, the click alternations work fine. The first click opens the animation, and the second click closes the animation.

**The problem on my mobile site, the first click opens the animation, and the second animation runs immediately after with-out a second click. But in the fiddle it runs OK.**

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $(window).bind("orientationchange resize", function(e) {

        $('.home-mod').each(function() {

            var homeModule  = $(this).height(),
                homeTitle   = $(this).find('.home-title-button').outerHeight(),
                homeStart   = homeModule - homeTitle,
                homeOpen    = false;

            $(this).find('.mod-info').css("top", homeStart + "px");

            $(this).on('click', function () {

                if (homeOpen) {

                    // second click alternation
                    $(this).find('.mod-info').animate({ top: homeStart + "px" });
                    homeOpen = false;

                } else {

                    // first click alternation
                    $(this).find('.mod-info').animate({ top: 0 });
                    homeOpen = true; 

                }
            });

        }); 

    }).trigger("resize");

});
```

I'm really not sure why this would be happening. Using this in iScroll shouldnt cause any problems should it?


Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like it's a problem with the browser sending two click events, rather than an issue with your code. I may be incorrect though.

Comment: As a note you should make really sure that when you say a fiddle is a replication of the code you've quoted that it really is. In this case it wasn't and this may well have made it harder for people to answer your question.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I think it must something like what you saying. It's seems exactly like its running a double click. The only difference with my code is that it is in iScroll. I will post another fiddle an see if i can replicate my error.

Answer (score 3):

firstly : window load happens

you are calling

```
.trigger("resize");
```

which activates the bind on click.

`later on` - if the window load happens again - it retrigger the code which again - re bind the click

Comment: Why in every loop? The `.trigger("resize")` isn't part of the resize event handler.

Comment: I thought that at first. I'm not sure what that quoted code has to do with it but the click is getting set from inside the resize event so multiple resizes or orientation changes could cause "entertainment" for you.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist look closely. the windows loads - and it bind the resize event. which tells him what to do with click event. later he trigger the reisize again which again cause him to add click function

Comment: @RoyiNamir What I should have done was check the jsFiddle, which I assumed to be the same as the code included in the question (and which was said to be working fine). You may very well be correct, should be easy enough to find out.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: that line you have quoted only causes it to get added once though. Its only when that event occurs on its own elsewhere that multiple clicks get added. Your answer does seem to be somewhat confusing I'm afraid to say.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: The fiddle sadly is not the same (it lacks the resize handler). If you look at my answer I created the fiddle with this code as a replication of the bug and then fixed it using .off to remove the clicks before adding the new ones. I suspect that closure could be used to save having to rebind things multiple times too but I went for the simpler approach with minimum code rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your fiddle code and your live code is the presence of the resize/orientation handler.

All your other code is inside that meaning that it will get run every time your run your resize handler. http://jsfiddle.net/uTV5k/20/ is a variant of your fiddle with that handler back in. It misbehaves badly.

You can fix this by removing the old click handlers before adding the new ones using `.off('click')`.

This fiddle includes this update and seems to behave again: http://jsfiddle.net/uTV5k/21/

The other (and possibly better) way of fixing this issue is to just recalculate the values you need to in the on resize and store them more globally. Then your click functions can be added once and refer to these global values. This is a much bigger code rewrite and I just went for the very simple fix to highlight your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I figured the orientation part could be causing the issue. I tried your snippet.. $(this).off('click').on('click', function () { but still did the same. I complete removed the orientation and put it in a 'document ready' and still reacts like I'm double clicking. Very bizarre.